# How to allow Object creation of a class on only particular classes in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm, class, oop, design-patterns

In PHP, let there be four classes A, B, C, and D. None of them inherits the other. They are all independent classes. Now, I want only B and C to be able to create Objects of the class A. D Should not be able to create the Object of class A.

Can this be done in PHP? If So, how? I tried refreshing my object oriented concepts, but can't seem to find an appropriate answer in PHP.

Little help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For the guy who down voted, please let me know why?

Comment: I think function `debug_backtrace()` will help you here

Comment: @ChetanAmeta Ok Lemmi check it out. Thanks

Comment: see the example in my answer

Comment: perhaps you can explain why you want to do this? this may enable better suggestions to solve your actual problem.

Comment: @SamHolder I have already mentioned the reason. In my project, I do not want anyone to create the Object of Class A in any other class other than classes B and C. Example. Class A can be a ConnectionHandler class which will handle all db connections, and I don't want those functions to be used anywhere else, other than the Classes that are meant to use it. I hope you understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here function [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) will help you. Have a look on below example.

```
class A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo debug_backtrace()[1]['class'];
    }
}

class B
{
    public function createObj()
    {
        $obj = new A();
    }
}

class C
{
    public function createObj()
    {
        $obj = new A();
    }
}

class D
{
    public function createObj()
    {
        $obj = new A();
    }
}

$o = new B();
$o->createObj(); //echo B

$o = new C();
$o->createObj(); //echo C

$o = new D();
$o->createObj(); //echo D
```

Here in `__construct` of class `A` you can put condition according to your requirement.

But IMHO inheritance and abstraction is the better option for the task.

Comment: This looks like it's gnna work and is what @arkascha pointed out at #2 in his answer. I'll try it out, and get back.

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not offer any explicit means for such a limitation.

Although this questions sounds odd to me (*why* would one want to do that?) I can imagine two possible approaches here, both with severe disadvantages:

1. You could try to limit access to the class definition: 
   Before being able to instantiate an object of a certain class the class definition must be known. Two strategies are used for that:

   a) Explicit inclusion statements loading the class definition where required. This can obviously be blocked by means of the base system. Either by brute permission denial, so if you juggle with the file permissions, though this would result in a runtime error. Or by replacing the actual files, for example by using a cascade of symbolic links changed as required.

   b) Some auto loading mechanism. This scenario obviously allows to implement an additional filter step which might load some fake class definition or simply throw an error in case access to the target class should be denied.
2. you could actively prevent the object creation in an active manner. Again two variants:

   a) Throw an exception inside the class constructor. A pretty rude thing to do...

   b) Follow the factory pattern and declare the class constructor non-public and only offer a static generator method as the sole way to instantiate an object of the class. This is more transparent, methods can raise exceptions or deny to return the expected result.

For this you obviously need some information you can decide upon if the request should be granted or not. It should be possible to evaluate the execution stack to detect from what code section the object creation was triggered. A lexical analyse of that information or a comparison against some catalog could form the base of a decision.

But as said in the beginning: all approaches have disadvantages. This sounds more like a miss usage of the possibilities... Although... possibilities are there to be explored, right? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am going to play around with the second point that you mentioned. And since I am not as experienced as you in this field, your first point just went over my head. For the sake of understanding, can you please provide any links that I can read into?

Comment: Could you state in more detail what exactly it is that you don't understand in that first point?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Before being able to instantiate an object of a certain class the class definition must be known"?

Comment: Well, try something like `$obj = new MyClass;` before you actually included the implementation of that class. It obviously won't work. That is what I mean by "it must be known".